# Insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am following along with a coding book called "Learning Spring Boot 3.0 Third Edition" by Greg L. Turnquist ISBN 978-1-80323-330-7.

I am using Windows 11 on an HP Laptop with Spring Tool Suite 4 installed along with Java 17.

The problem that I have in chapter 4 “Securing an Application with Spring Boot” is that the code has deprecated elements for `SecurityFilterChain`. The original code from the book had:

```java
@Bean 
SecurityFilterChain configureSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll() 
            .requestMatchers("/", "/search").authenticated() 
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").authenticated() 
            .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/new-video", "/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .anyRequest().denyAll() 
            .and()
        .formLogin() 
            .and() 
        .httpBasic(); 

    return http.build(); 
}
```

This code had numerous errors because `.authorizeHttpRequests()` and `.authorizeRequests()` have been deprecated, so I edited the code to say:

```java
@Bean 
SecurityFilterChain configureSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 

        auth-> auth.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll() 
            .requestMatchers("/", "/search").authenticated()  
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").authenticated() 
            .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/new-video" "/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
            .anyRequest().denyAll() 
            .and() 
        .formLogin()
            .and() 
        .httpBasic(); 

        return http.build(); 
    } 
}
```

The line with `.httpBasic();` shows the error:

> Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

So that is where I am stuck at, no other errors in the code.  Does anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it below this way, it should work.

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests((request) -> 
            request.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/search").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/new-video","/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().denyAll())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();

}
```

Comment: Error at compile time is:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configureSecurity' defined in class path resource [blue/ch4/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configureSecurity' threw exception with message: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method withDefaults() is undefined for the type Customizer
 The method withDefaults() is undefined for the type Customizer

Comment: Please share your spring security version and the code you write in the security config.

Comment: I am using spring security 6 I believe but not 100% sure. Is there a way to get the spring security version (pom file does not show a version number and not sure how to show in spring CLI)

Comment: Whether its books or online videos I am always given code that does not work for Spring Security